# Comma after "first-hand"

Tags: commas

Is a comma needed after first-hand?

I witnessed first-hand the genuine enjoyment these boys gained from socializing with one another.

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: The presence of a comma is not generally based on the use of a particular word or phrase, but rather the construction of the sentence as a whole.  One fairly good test is whether you would insert a brief pause at that point when speaking the sentence -- the comma implies a pause.

Comment: It's not required and would normally not be used here. However, you could put *first-hand* between a pair of commas if you wished to make it nonrestrictive parenthetical information.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no need for a comma in the sentence "I witnessed first-hand the genuine enjoyment these boys gained from socializing with one another."

The comma is used in many contexts and languages, mainly for separating parts of a sentence such as clauses, and items in lists, particularly when there are three or more items listed. However, in the sample sentence there is no such situation.